# Unable to change query values in wordpress query.php

Tags: mysql, woocommerce, query-optimization, woothemes

My website having woo commerce theme is very slow in loading specially product summary page takes almost 3 minutes in loading.Now i want to change product summary page main query but unable to find way so that i will be able to change/optimize my query.Query output value is given below.I change $query in Query.php but when i execute page then there is no change in query and it is showing same query.Please guide if any other change is necessary.
Previous and new values in query.php are given below.

Previous value

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT  post_id
    FROM  $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->posts
    WHERE  ID = post_id
      AND  post_type = %s
      AND  meta_key = '_wp_old_slug'
      AND  meta_value = %s",
    $post_type, $wp_query->query_vars['name']);
```

New value(want to use this value instead of above)

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id
          FROM $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->posts
          WHERE ID = post_id" );
```

Query value used for page data

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_bkkf_posts.ID
FROM wp_bkkf_posts
INNER JOIN wp_bkkf_postmeta
ON ( wp_bkkf_posts.ID = wp_bkkf_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( ( wp_bkkf_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility'
AND wp_bkkf_postmeta.meta_value IN ('visible','catalog') ) )
AND wp_bkkf_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (wp_bkkf_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_bkkf_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_bkkf_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_bkkf_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_bkkf_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0, 12
```

Actually i don't want to use following values in query.

```
AND ( ( wp_bkkf_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility'
AND wp_bkkf_postmeta.meta_value IN ('visible','catalog') ) )
AND wp_bkkf_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (wp_bkkf_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_bkkf_posts.post_status = 'private')
```

Show create table output is given below

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_bkkf_postmeta` (                                                               
`meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                          
`post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',                                             
`meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,                                
`meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,                                               
PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),                                                                        
KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),                                                                      
KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))                                                                
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=30883570 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci      

CREATE TABLE `wp_bkkf_posts` (                                                                  
`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                               
`post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',                                         
`post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',                                    
`post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',                                
`post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,                                    
`post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,                                          
`post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,                                        
`post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',                
`comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',                
`ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',                   
`post_password` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',                     
`post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',                        
`to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,                                             
`pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,                                              
`post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',                                
`post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',                            
`post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,                           
`post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',                                         
`guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',                             
`menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',                                                      
`post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',                     
`post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',                   
`comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',                                                
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),                                                                             
KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),                                                             
KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),                            
KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),                                                              
KEY `post_author` (`post_author`),                                                              
KEY `post_idx` (`post_type`,`post_status`)                                                      
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1556181 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

If anyone have idea regarding $query value change then please guide,also please share other file names where change required..thanks.

Comment: Which are you asking:  Why did woo not change the query? or...  How can this query (which one?) be made faster?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the table sizes.

Comment: Sir..table size is wp_bkkf_postmeta 2581.78 MB and wp_bkkf_posts 590.62 MB,Secondly please guide how to check show create table..thanks

Comment: now i update show create table output at top please check..thanks

Comment: If anyone have some idea regarding other file changes for permanent values changes then please guide,what i require is that i want to use only following vlaues in page summary query...SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_bkkf_posts.ID
    FROM  wp_bkkf_posts
    LIMIT  0, 12

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_bkkf_posts.ID FROM wp_bkkf_posts LIMIT 0, 12;`

Comment: Output is given below..id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
1  SIMPLE  wp_bkkf_posts  index  NULL PRIMARY  8  NULL 1238309  Using index

Comment: Sir..output of your quer is above,if possible please guide for above query which type of php files need to be changes or where i change value so that above query is in use for page output..thanks.

Comment: Finding the first 12 ids is very fast.  Counting all 1238309 rows takes a long time.  Consider doing that count once a day, saving the count somewhere, then saying "out of about 1,200,000 posts".  The exact number is too costly to get and not useful to the end user.  Then you can get rid of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to make the query run much faster.

Comment: Do you expect the user to paginate though 100,000 pages to see all the posts?  Why do you even show the 12 _oldest_ posts?  Those seem useless.  Maybe `DESC` would be interesting?

Comment: Actully this is requirement,no issue regarding number of rows as query is fast when i remove all And and Group by and order by from query.Now my problem is that i am unable to change query as don't have idea where i change query value to exclude and and goroup and order by from my query.

Comment: So, the question is really about woo commerce, not MySQL?  I added a tag.

Comment: So..anyone have some idea,how ot modify woo themes for above mentioned query changes?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(meta_key)) FROM wp_bkkf_postmeta;
```

If that comes out less than 191, then do these:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_bkkf_postmeta
    MODIFY `meta_key` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    DROP KEY `post_id`,
    ADD INDEX pm (post_id, meta_key);
```

Consider getting rid of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`; it probably is a slowdown.  However losing that will lose the "out of ..." clause on the page.

If you toss the entire `WHERE` then the `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` can go away, too:

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_bkkf_posts.ID
    FROM  wp_bkkf_posts
    ORDER BY  wp_bkkf_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_bkkf_posts.post_title ASC
    LIMIT  0, 12
```

That will run faster.  Still, it will need to scan the entire 1.5 million row table.  Why you would want that particular `ORDER BY`?

Comment: During alter table query following error appears..ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'post_id'; check that column/key exists

Comment: Secondly now i use only following value in query.php file but after page execution again complete query visible at my webpage("http://www.shopsexactly.com/?post_type=product")...$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->posts" );  Is there any other value need to change

Comment: Sir..if there is any issue in above question then inform..thanks

Comment: Strange.  I copied your `CREATE`, then my `ALTER`.  I got no errors.  Check your `CREATE`.

Comment: please also check my second response regarding when i change value $query in query.php then why no change in output.Is there any other change required?

Comment: In that query...  You don't need postmeta f you are only looking for post_id values.  Joining the tables costs a lot (in this context).

Comment: Sir..do you have idea how to toss entire where in woo commerece

Comment: I am ignorant of Woo.  I spend too much time trying to work around 3rd party software that seems to get in the way of talking to MySQL.